# Android and jQuery Problem (might also be an asp.net issue?)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, android

Hello I'm programming an Web-Application with asp.net and jQuery (parts of it in jQueryMobile).
I can't use the loading-animations of jQueryMobile as they don't work with my aspx sites. So i implemented my own loading animation on several pages. Which looks like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loading").addClass("hidden");
        $("a.ui-btn").removeClass("hidden");
        $("a").click(function () {
            $("#loading").removeClass("hidden");
            $("a.ui-btn").addClass("hidden");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Now the problem:
on any Desktop Browser, on Mobile Opera and on any Safari-Based Browser (like on iPhone and iPad) everything works as one would expect it, except of the integrated Android-Browser (which is as far as i know a Chrome-derviate).
On these devices the loading animation doesn't show when i click a button. But(!) after the following page loaded and one uses the back-button of the Browser the animation shows up and one can't acces the normal page...
I don't understand what exactly happens here. Seems like a racing condition or something similar to me?! And how can i solve this?